# Error message of SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument trying to import time into Python

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import time

prtyear = time.strftime("%Y")

print(prtyear)

Works in console but gets the error message when running in PY code.  Similar problem trying to import Glob as well.  It is like I am not connected to the proper libraries.

Note I am new to Pycharm, Python and even Stackoverflow so everything is suspect as I am pounding thru an online Python course.   Python version is 3.11.4 and Pycharm is Community 2023.1,3
```

Trying to get time and instead get the error message pointing to the import time line of code

I have searched Stackoverflow and saw people with similar problems but not really a solution that I recognized.  Not trying to be lazy here.

Comment: Sounds like you wrote some broken code and named it `time.py`, or something else that clashes with a standard library module. Post the complete error message, including the full stack trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to check what is being targeted by your run command. Testing in a new environment on my computer, there was no issue running those three lines of code. This might not solve your problem, but please try right clicking on the file in PyCharm and selecting Run 'main' (or whatever your file is named).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).